# drop down list does not work html css

Tags: css, hover, pseudo-class

I have a problem and can't solve it.
I have created this HTML page, but the `:hover` selector on `#drop` doesn't work.

```css
#drop {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    padding: 10px;
}
#droplist {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
#droplist a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: olivedrab;
    padding: 10px;
}
#drop:hover #droplist {
    display: block;
}
#droplist a:hover {
    background-color: olive;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<!--   ...   -->
<body>
    <div id="pagina">
        <div id="drop">Hover for open the menu</div>
        <div id="droplist">
            <a href="#a">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#b">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#c">Link 3</a>
        </div>
        <br/>text text text text text text text text text
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I try to hover over the div with id `#drop` but the element `#droplist` doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't select `#drop:hover #droplist` because `#droplist` is not a child of `#drop`.

Use `#drop:hover + #droplist` instead.

the [`element1 + element2`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp) selector is used to select and style every `element2` that are placed immediately after `element1`

```css
#drop {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  padding: 10px;
}

#droplist {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

#droplist a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: olivedrab;
  padding: 10px;
}

#drop:hover+#droplist {
  display: block;
}

#droplist a:hover {
  background-color: olive;
}

#droplist:hover {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<!--   ...   -->

<body>
  <div id="pagina">
    <div id="drop">Hover for open the menu</div>
    <div id="droplist">
      <a href="#a">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#b">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#c">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT**: you might want to add in

```
#droplist:hover {
   display: block
}
```

so that the drop down menu doesn't disappear, when you hover it

Comment: no problem Matteo, look at my Edit above (add `#droplist:hover {display: block}` to your code). Also consider upvoting & accepting the answer for future users. Thanks!